# Is it okay to work on Ubuntu while another person working on the same project is working on Windows 7?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, windows-7, ubuntu-14.04

Is it fine to work on Ubuntu while another person working with me on the same project is working on Windows 7?

We are using Python 2.7, and Flask, and have set up matching virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing/manipulating Operating system specific information ?
For example, some file attributes, other than the basic attributes, are different on both systems.

Comment: i don't think so, but i'll look out for those. thanks!